# Error installing BigVis package in RStudio Version 3.0.2

Tags: r, github, package, rstudio, devtools

When I run the code to install BigVis package from GitHub as follows,
 `devtools::install_github("bigvis")`
I get the following output:

```
Installing github repo bigvis/master from hadley
Downloading master.zip from https://github.com/hadley/bigvis/archive/master.zip
Installing package from /var/folders/dl/hhhtf5f52hz7qrw93wfyk_6h0000gn/T//RtmpgkDD2j/master.zip
arguments 'minimized' and 'invisible' are for Windows only
Installing bigvis
'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R'  \
  --vanilla CMD INSTALL  \
  '/private/var/folders/dl/hhhtf5f52hz7qrw93wfyk_6h0000gn/T/RtmpgkDD2j/devtools259f1fe8bc61/bigvis-master'  \
  --library='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library'  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'bigvis' ...
** libs
sh: make: command not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'bigvis'
* removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/bigvis'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

DO YOU HAVE ANY IDEA HOW I MAY FIX IT? THANKS

Comment: You might like to write the question you have, rather than hope the reader infers it from the error message you quote.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `sh: make: command not found` tells you that the program `sh` could not find the program `make`.  So my crystal ball tells me you might need to install GNU make.  But I know nothing about RStudio nor BigVis.